# error whilst installing prestashop via docker-compose up

Tags: mysql, docker, prestashop

Can somebody please help when I try to install a Prestashop local environment I receive this error and when I visit localhost it refuses to connect. for any more details don't hesitate to aks. thank you

**the docker log is as shown below**

```
021-01-31T23:29:12.526523Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.

2021-01-31T23:29:12.548265Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables

2021-01-31T23:29:12.548384Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...

2021-01-31T23:29:12.567231Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.

2021-01-31T23:29:12.567703Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 96 redo rollback segment(s) found. 96 redo rollback segment(s) are active.

2021-01-31T23:29:12.567730Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 32 non-redo rollback segment(s) are active.

2021-01-31T23:29:12.568365Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 5.7.33 started; log sequence number 41897827

2021-01-31T23:29:12.568546Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool

2021-01-31T23:29:12.568669Z 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.

2021-01-31T23:29:12.571447Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 210131 23:29:12

2021-01-31T23:29:12.573313Z 0 [Note] Found ca.pem, server-cert.pem and server-key.pem in data directory. Trying to enable SSL support using them.

2021-01-31T23:29:12.573351Z 0 [Note] Skipping generation of SSL certificates as certificate files are present in data directory.

2021-01-31T23:29:12.574119Z 0 [Warning] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.

2021-01-31T23:29:12.574165Z 0 [Note] Skipping generation of RSA key pair as key files are present in data directory.

2021-01-31T23:29:12.574670Z 0 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306

2021-01-31T23:29:12.574734Z 0 [Note] IPv6 is available.

2021-01-31T23:29:12.574745Z 0 [Note] - '::' resolves to '::';

2021-01-31T23:29:12.574758Z 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.

2021-01-31T23:29:12.578313Z 0 [Warning] Insecure configuration for --pid-file: Location '/var/run/mysqld' in the path is accessible to all OS users. Consider choosing a different directory.

2021-01-31T23:29:12.595011Z 0 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events

2021-01-31T23:29:12.595447Z 0 [Note] mysqld: ready for connections.

**Version: '5.7.33' socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' port: 3306 MySQL Community Server (GPL)
2021-01-31T23:29:13.303581Z 2 [Note] Got an error reading communication packets**
```

Comment: This question has nothing to do with programming, therefore it is off topic here on SO. The dba sister site of SO provides help with database admin related questions like this one.